# Is there vApp-like support in Google Cloud?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I have set up a nice VM network in Google Cloud Compute Engine. I would like to create another identical one. Is it possible to do so without going through the same steps again?

Comment: Do yourself a favor and learn something like Ansible. http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/guide_gce.html You'll need to do it one more time, but after that you've got a recipe for launching as many as you want. Handy skill.

Comment: @ceejayoz I was also thinking about using vagrant or the gcloud tool directly. Do you recommend an approach among the three? Also, from google cloud's point of view, what would the setup look like? One project per replica? All replicas lying under one project?